# Using a New system.out.println() for every line or using + "\n" for every new line?

Tags: java

I am a junior Developer in Java and I'd like to know what is the preferred or better way to print multiple lines of code:

```
System.out.println("Hello world!");
System.out.println("I am a junior Developer");
```

or

````
System.out.println("Hello world" + "\n"```
+ "I am a junior Developer");```
````

Comment: Note that as you start building more complex software, you normally won't be using `System.out` at all; instead, you'll use a logger tool like [SLF4J](http://slf4j.org/) and distribute the log lines throughout your application.

Answer (score 3):

Prefer the first, `"\n"` is not the correct sequence for newline on Windows. You **could** use

```
System.out.println("Hello world" + System.lineSeparator()
        + "I am a junior Developer");
```

which potentially avoids an extra (implicit) `flush()` but standard io is generally slow anyway.

Comment: Also the first one is more readable (but please put each `println` on a separate line)